# Url.Action won't use default area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have two areas: "" and "Admin".
I had some code in my Admin layout, which I needed to recreate in my Default Area layout:

```
@Url.Action("Go", "Notifications", New With {.id = item.ID})
```

In the admin layout it would render the link as ~/Admin/Notifications/Go/[id] which is fine, as users of this area have the correct Authentication to reach that action, and they were in the Admin area in the first place so it makes sense...

But now **I have copied it to my Default Area, and it will not stop rendering /Admin/ at the beginning no matter what I do**.. (Seriously what?)

**The single one that does work yet is entirely useless, unhelpful and infuriating.** (Thanks again Microsoft)

```
@Url.Action("Go", "Notifications", New With {.area = ""})
```

**Variations I have tried that still don't work**

```
@Url.Action("Go", "Notifications", New With {.area = "", .id = item.ID})
@Url.Action("Go", "Notifications", New With {.id = item.ID, .area = ""})
@Url.Action("Go", "Notifications", New With {.Area = "", .id = item.ID})
@Url.Action("Go", "Notifications", New With {.id = item.ID, .Area = ""})
@Url.Action("Go", "Notifications", New With {.id = item.ID, .area = String.Empty})
```

In the meantime I will have to use

```
<a href="/Notifications/Go/@item.ID">Notifications</a>
```

But **I am looking for an answer to what on earth this ridiculous functionality is, and how to overcome it with Url.Action**, as I use this throughout the project for dynamic URLS.

I'm beginning to completely lose faith in MS VB.NET MVC.

Comment: do you have any specific routes that use this action result and controller that may be interfering? Does it do this no matter what actionresult/controller are specified, or just this combination?

Comment: Hi Carl. No I don't have any routes to do with that location, and yes it happens even if I change the Controller/Action. Oddly though it works fine if the only paramater I pass is area, but as soon as I pass the ID too then it has a tantrum, as do I haha. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you post your routes and your area routes as well?